# What is the geography of (now obsolete) usage of the word фамилия to mean 'wife'?

Tags: лексикон, литература, лингвистика, диалект

While Valentin Kiparsky claimed (in Omagiu lui Iordan) that this usage is a calque from Tatar and therefore found in the Russian varieties spoken in and near Kazan (the area of the Tatar-speaking former Kazan Khanate), he gives no source for this and only cites one occurrence in a novel by an author who did go to university in Kazan (but was not born there).

Is there any evidence of the word *фамилия* being used with the meaning of "wife" beyond this area?

Comment: Unfortunately, "if anyone has anything to add to this, I'd appreciate it" is not a question we can answer here. Do you have a concrete, answerable question? If yes, please edit the post and add it there. Thank you!

Comment: Why do Russians love the word calque so much? It used so rarely in linguistics anymore. We use **loanword** or **loan translation**: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+calque+from%2C+a+loanword+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @CocoPop: because "loanword" and "calque" mean different things. _хризантема_ is a loanword from Greek  (< _χρῡσανθής_, "golden flower") , _златоцвет_ is a calque. Apparently, "loan translation" is a synonym for "calque" (I didn't know that), but it looks like it's used less: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+calque+from%2Ca+loan+translation+from&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Quassnoi I see. I was always curious about that. Thank you)))